# Can you still get water in the Nether by melting ice?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

You used to be able to melt ice in the Nether, and then it would become water and this was the only way to get water to the Nether. Can you still do this or has it been patched?

Comment: Is there a reason you think this might have been patched?

Comment: Nope. Just not sure, a lot of updates have come out since the last time I used this, so they may have slipped in a fix.

Answer (score -1):

This was asked before for Java edition, [read for reference](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/30803/87579):

> It used to be possible to get water into the Nether with this, but as of Minecraft 1.3.1, ice blocks in the Nether simply disappear when they're broken (or when they melt from a light source).
> Ice blocks can now be legitimately obtained in survival mode by harvesting them with a Silk Touch enchanted pickaxe. However, the ability for ice to create water in the Nether was removed.

And according to [Minecraft wikia](https://minecraft.wiki/w/The_Nether#Traits):

> There is no way to place liquid water in the Nether without the use of commands, except inside a cauldron.
> Ice that is melted or smashed in the Nether does not produce water.

So no, you cannot get water into the Nether using ice blocks.

The only way to have water in the Nether was [a bug involving lava and glow lichen](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-213264) in snapshot 21w03a, but it was fixed.

Comment: Is this not a duplicate?

Comment: @Wrigglenite not sure, since the first question was asked for Minecraft Java and at the time it was actually possibile, then it was changed. This one regards Minecraft Bedrock, and it's still not possible. I linked the answer for reference, if you believe it's a dupe I'll vote it.

Comment: i mean, they asked for bedrock edition, not java, so snapshots arent a thing, but, bedrock edition was made after they patched ice being able to create water in the nether so it isnt likely.

Comment: @Parkerdaboss216 I mentioned the snapshot just for reference